# How does Linux measure elapsed time of a particular process?

Tags: linux, process, elapsedtime

When I look at [ps command manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), it offers elapsed time measurement for each process, no matter this process is still alive. However, when I check /proc//stat, it only records the start time, CPU time and User time. I tried to add CPU time and User time, but the result doesn't match what elapsed time shows. Hence I'd like to look for suggestion on the direction to measure elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

The elapsed time displayed by ps is just current time - start time.  So literally just the elapsed wall clock time since the process started.

The utime and stime in /proc/stat are a measure of the total amount of time the process has actually been running on the system (user time and system time), not counting any time spent blocked waiting for something.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I have another follow up questions based on your answer: How do I get end time of process from other process since I may not always using monitor mechanism like waitpid/poll/epoll wait when this process is still running. If I want to get the lifecycle of this process after its death. What information can I get from linux kernel or I have to put time stamp snapshot on this process before it exits?

Comment: The only (easy) way to get info about an arbitrary other process is to read /proc/pid/stat (or other /proc/pid files) -- wait can only be used for children.  When a process dies, it becomes a zombie and its stats can still be read, up until its parent collects it and the process goes away completely.  If you are trying to monitor a process that is not your child, there can be races with what the parent is doing.